# I registered my contract in Chainlink Keepers, function checkUpkeep returns true, however performUpkeep is not executing

Tags: solidity, chainlink

Like the title says, it seems all the conditions for a keeper to run performUpkeep have been met, yet it is not being called.

I have verify my smart contract, make it Kepper Compatible, Fund the Keeper with sufficient LINK.

Here is the upkeep link: https://keepers.chain.link/mumbai/1560

Here is the contract: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x5BdfE445c664020988f857b42E6772385da0EdB6#code

Here is the relevant code:

```
 function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /* checkData */
    )
        public
        view
        override
        returns (
            bool upkeepNeeded,
            bytes memory /* performData */
        )
    {
        bool timePassed = ((block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp) > interval); // keep track of betting
        bool hasPlayers = upBetAddresses.length > 0 ||
            downBetAddresses.length > 0;
        upkeepNeeded = (timePassed && hasPlayers);
        return (upkeepNeeded, "0x0");
    }

    // function to send MATIC to the winners
    function performUpkeep(
        bytes calldata /* performData */
    ) external override {
        // this is the way to get checkUpKeep function. we only need 1 parameter, therefore (bool upkeepNeede, ) next is blank.
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        if (!upkeepNeeded) {
            revert BET_UPKEEP_NOT_NEEDED();
        }
        //We highly recommend revalidating the upkeep in the performUpkeep function
        if ((block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp) > interval) {
            executePlaceBet();
            lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        }
        emit Perform_UpKeep();
    }

    // placing bet with simple up and down
    function executePlaceBet() private {
     //code
    }
```

Use Hardhat to deploy code. Some relevant code:

```
const deployedVerifyContract = await verifyContract.deploy(INTERVAL, FEE);
```

Create index.js for constants

```
const FEE = ethers.utils.parseEther("1");
const INTERVAL = 3600;
```

Upkeep when 1 hour have passed and there are players in array / dapp
[image]

Comment: Could you add what your checkupkeep and performupkeep are returning? Also it might be easier to keep the time interval smaller - I called `perforumUpkeep` just to see if it would go through, and it did - but now we have to wait 3600 seconds

Comment: I want checkUpKeep to wait for 1 hour and check the players in betting and if condition is true then execute performUpKeep. I need to do it every hour because Data feed of ETH/USD changes every hour. There is no logic for PerformUpKeep to wait for another 1 hour / 3600 seconds before executing.

Comment: Looks like it's working now. I'm willing to bet it's the Mumbai testnet having issues - I always recommend not using a polygon testnet.

Comment: I am creating the this project for chainlink Hackathon. They suggested to use L2 solution to create project. Can you please check again. The thing is, I have updated my smart contract to add some functions. I have manually execute performUpKeep and it performing all the functions. But now keeper stop working for new Contract.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your gas limit may be too low. I simulated the transaction and it looks like it would use 169,872 gas. Your gas limit is 50,000. I'd recommend recreating the upkeep with some buffer. Maybe with a gas limit of 300,000 to be safe?

Answer (score 1):

Hey [Ayush](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/101000/aayush-gupta)

I wasn't able to replicate your issue.  I took the verified version of your contract and changed interval to 60 seconds.  It's deployed [here](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x4ccdc5f3b2e113a5a1cbcea54fc10932e0d94b33) (unverified) and the events are [here](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x4ccdc5f3b2e113a5a1cbcea54fc10932e0d94b33#events).

I also registered it as an [upkeep](https://keepers.chain.link/mumbai/1563)

As long as a bet is placed, it works.  You can see from the History on my upkeep that `performUpkeep` gets called. You can also see the bets I placed in the the etherscan link I linked to above.

My test account's transactions are [here](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x208AA722Aca42399eaC5192EE778e4D42f4E5De3)